# C function to count amount of same Parent Child values

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

i'm working new with binary tree and just trying to write this Function,
which give the number of node with the same Parent value, the problem with my code that it
give 0 as result or wrong number!

```
int x=0;
int amountSameParentChild(TreeNode *node){
    if((node!=NULL) && (node->left!=NULL || node->right!=NULL)){
            if (node->data==node->left->data||node->data==node->right->data){
                x++;
                amountSameParentChild(node->left);
                amountSameParentChild(node->right);
            }
     }
     return x;
}

    int main()
    {
        int upperLimit = 10;
        int entries[upperLimit];
        int *results = malloc(sizeof(int));
    
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < upperLimit; i++)
        {
            int randomEntry = rand() % (5);
            entries[i] = randomEntry;
        }
        TreeNode *root = newNode(0);
        root = createRandomTree(entries, root, 0, upperLimit);
        printAsTree(root, 10);
        printf("%d\n", amountSameParentChild(root));
    }
```

Comment: `if (node->data==node->left->data)` You also reach that line if `node->left` is `NULL`.

Comment: You should add some sample tree together with your expected result.

Comment: There are multiple errors in this code, and Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service. You should isolate one problem to a specific part of the code. Then, if you do not understand that part, you could ask Stack Overflow about it. However, having isolated the problem to one part of the code, you would likely know what is wrong with that part of the code. If you do not know how to do basic debugging to trace programs and isolate problems, then you need to study that or ask your school for assistance. Such teaching is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: “number of node with the same Parent value” is not clear. If node 0 has the value 37 and node 0 has children 1 and 2 with values 38 and 39, and they have children 3, 4, 5, 6 with values 37, 93, 93, and 93, does that make the “number of node with same Parent value” one because there is one node (3) with the same value as the starting parent (0), even though 3 is a grandchild, not a direct child, of node 0? Or is the number zero because no child has the same value as its specific parent?

Comment: `if (node->data==node->left->data||node->data==node->right->data)` After your edit you have even 2 accesses to pointers that might be `NULL`. Without adding sample data or explaining what you regard to be "same parant child nodes" it is hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int amountSameParentChild( TreeNode *node ) {
    return 0;
}
```

By definition, the answer will always be zero...

By definition, values of all 'left subtree' nodes are LESS THAN the parent/root node, and 'right subtree' values GREATER THAN.

No child node can/will have the same value as its parent...